# Openpyxl: set background color to a row and column Attribute Error

Tags: python, openpyxl

having looked at a few examples over here I tried to set background color to an entire row and column. I have done

```
 import openpyxl
 from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
 wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(self.inputfile)
 ws = wb.active
 ws['A1'].fill = PatternFill(bgColor="FFC7CE", fill_type = "solid")`
```

I get an Attribute error if I do `ws[1].fill =PatternFill(bgColor="FFC7CE", fill_type = "solid")

The above code fills a single cell(A1). But how do I go forward if I want to fill an entire row(1), and an entire column(A).

Comment: This is covered in the documentation: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html#applying-styles

Comment: @CharlieClark Following the documentation the following does not work for me: row = ws.row_dimensions[1]
row.font = Font(bold=True), am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Iterates all columns, starting at the Column specified in the `min_col=1` argument.
Ends after one row, as the row arguments `min_row=1` and `max_row=1` are equal.
Arguments `min_row/max_row` can point to any row, even also outside data.

```
  for rows in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1, min_col=1):
    for cell in rows:
      cell.fill = PatternFill(bgColor="FFC7CE", fill_type = "solid")
```

For entire Column, use:

```
iter_cols(min_col=None, max_col=None, min_row=None, max_row=None)
```

If you only  give `min_*` attribute values, max row/column are used.

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - openpyxl:2.4.1***

Answer (score 5):

Slight modification on the accepted answer (white background):

```
   for rows in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=40, min_col=1, max_col=40):
    for cell in rows:
        cell.fill = PatternFill(start_color='00FFFFFF', end_color='00FFFFFF', fill_type="solid")
```

This provides a white fill on the sheet starting at row 1 column 1 and going to row 40 and column 40.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the accepted answer but row background was always black, So i have to change the `PatternFill` to following.

```
  cell.fill = PatternFill(start_color='FFC7CE', end_color='FFC7CE', fill_type = "solid")
```