# Export data to empty cell row Openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to automate number groupings of several lists by exporting the data to ms excel using openpyxl. The output is a list of lists with two sets of numbers per element, the first set being the matched number (0 to 99), and the second is the index number where they matched.

```
def variable_str_to_list_pairs_overlapping (str):
    return [''.join(pair) for pair in zip(str[:-1], str[1:])]

list1 = variable_str_to_list_pairs_overlapping (list1)
list2 = variable_str_to_list_pairs_overlapping (list2)

lst_result = []
for i in range(len(list2)):
     if list1[i] == list2[i]:
     data = [list1[i], i]
     data[0] = int(list1[i])
     lst_result.append(data)
print(lst_result)
```

Output:

```
    [[7, 265], [8, 281], [2, 303], [8, 332], [7, 450], [1, 544], [0, 
    737], [9, 805], [2, 970], [4, 1103], [4, 1145], [8, 1303], [1, 
    1575], [4, 1592], [2, 1593], [3, 1948], [4, 2200], [5, 2419], [3, 
    2464], [9, 2477], [1, 2529], [6, 2785], [2, 2842], [8, 2843], [7, 
    2930], [3, 2991], [8, 3096], [3, 3248], [2, 3437], [7, 3438], [8, 
    3511], [0, 3522], [0, 3523], [5, 3590], [6, 3621], [1, 3622], [2, 
    3671], [6, 3835], [7, 3876]]
```

I'm looking to export the data to excel in such a way that the first element is assigned as the row index and the second as the value inside the cell

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
dest_filename = 'openpyxltest.xlsx'
for x in lst_result:
    ws.cell(row = x[0] + 1, column = +2).value = x[1]
wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

Actual Output:
[image: Actual Output]

Desired Output:
[image: Desired Output]

What do I need to change in my code? Thank you in advance for the help. you guys are awesome! :)

Comment: @Patrick Artner I appreciate the feedback sir. I've edited my question. I apologize as I am quite new to programming. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the cells - you never adjust the *column* you write into - so it gets overwritten by later writes...

You could solve this by using a [defaultdict(list)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to collect all values of one key into a list, sort it and then create the xlsx from the dictionary like so:

```
lst_result = [[7, 265], [8, 281], [2, 303], [8, 332], [7, 450], [1, 544], [0, 
    737], [9, 805], [2, 970], [4, 1103], [4, 1145], [8, 1303], [1, 
    1575], [4, 1592], [2, 1593], [3, 1948], [4, 2200], [5, 2419], [3, 
    2464], [9, 2477], [1, 2529], [6, 2785], [2, 2842], [8, 2843], [7, 
    2930], [3, 2991], [8, 3096], [3, 3248], [2, 3437], [7, 3438], [8, 
    3511], [0, 3522], [0, 3523], [5, 3590], [6, 3621], [1, 3622], [2, 
    3671], [6, 3835], [7, 3876]]

from collections import defaultdict

# group all datapoints by 1st value
grpd_data = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in lst_result:
    grpd_data[k].append(v)

# sort all grouped values (not needed here, as inputs are sorted)
# for l in grpd_data:
#    grpd_data[l].sort()
```

grpd_data looks like:

```
# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: [737, 3522, 3523], 1: [544, 1575, 2529, 3622], 
#     2: [303, 970, 1593, 2842, 3437, 3671], 3: [1948, 2464, 2991, 3248], 
#     4: [1103, 1145, 1592, 2200], 5: [2419, 3590], 6: [2785, 3621, 3835], 
#     7: [265, 450, 2930, 3438, 3876], 8: [281, 332, 1303, 2843, 3096, 3511], 
#     9: [805, 2477]})
```

Then create the workbook:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
dest_filename = 'openpyxltest.xlsx'

for x,data in grpd_data.items():
    ws.cell(row = x + 1, column = 1).value = x
    for col,d in enumerate(data,2): 
        ws.cell(row = x + 1, column = col).value = d

wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

Output:

[image: resulting xlsx]

---

See:

- [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)
- [How does collections.defaultdict work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900578/how-does-collections-defaultdict-work)

Comment: Thank you sir, that worked like a charm. :) If I may, I would also like to ask, since I have several lst_result(s) from different lists, it would immensely help if I can plot them to excel in such a way where it can be indicated which list_result they come from. I was thinking of having the cells color-coded, i.e list_result1 cells are highlighted red, list_result2 would be in yellow, an so on. any insights on this?

Comment: @Marcky use different [new sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385689/add-a-new-sheet-to-a-existing-workbook-in-python) per list or [color your cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42288870/openpyxl-set-background-color-to-a-row-and-column-attribute-error). HTH

Comment: thank you very much sir, I really appreciate it. I'll look into the resources you provided.

Comment: FWIW the list should sort directly as desired.

Comment: @char in this case yes - because the input is sorted.. if not you need to sort the input or the groups.

Comment: Sure, I was just thinking aloud. `itertools.groupby` would an alternative approach.