# Iterating through an Excel file using openpyxl and python 3.8

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to do the following with this excel file:

```
Date        Order_ID      SKU
2/21/21     554-869       478899
2/21/21     554-869       458999
2/21/21     554-869       895869
2/23/21     452-215       142555
2/23/21     452-215       569899
2/23/21     452-215       478899
2/29/21     125-411       142575
2/29/21     125-411       511470
2/29/21     125-411       569895
```

I am trying to iterate through this spreadsheet and compare ORDER_ID from one row to the next.
Then I will highlight the group, so for example all Order_ID 544-869 rows will be highlighted blue
and all 452-215 Order_ID rows would be highlighted purple. Then the next group of 125-411 would go back to being highlighted blue...so alternating bands of color using the Order_ID column as the field I am comparing from one row to the next.

```
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=2, max_col=2, max_row=11):
  # color the first row blue here
  for row_next in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=3, min_col=2, max_col=2, max_row=12):
      for cell in row:
          for cell_next in row_next:
              if cell.value  ==  cell_next.value:
                  #some code here to color both rows same color
              if cell.value  !=  cell_next.value:
                  #some code here to color cell one color and cell_next the other color
```

I know this is too complicated and I am not clear what to do next.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Openpyxl: set background color to a row and column Attribute Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42288870/openpyxl-set-background-color-to-a-row-and-column-attribute-error)

Comment: You probaby want to look at using Excel's own conditional formatting to do this so that you can apply a single condition to a whole range.